# Plug-in program to obtain host program data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins

Thinking about visual studio(vs)'s plugin visual assist(va). When mouse right click some code in file, vs open a menu list there, and then you can click va's function such as 'find reference'. I guess that va needs vs data, but it is not vs initiative to pass to va.
In my opinion, I could design some interface for plug-in program to realize. As below:

```
void doSomething(string data, action callback);
```

'dada' is json/xml text, the host program can trans information into it. And it also can arise a callback to update itself after 'doSomething' is finished.
Maybe the host program call this function somewhere, but the 'data' only represents the state of that time. How can I do if the plugin program need host pragram's data in other time.BTW, the plugin program has its logic, I can't always pass data to it from the host.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Plugins interact with their hosts' object models, typically through dependency injection.  VS uses MEF.

Comment: could you expain what's hosts' object models? Can I get host's runtime object or call its method?

Comment: That depends on the host.  But usually yes.